How do I see the holders of a particular token?
I’m trying to map holders of specific tokens, issue im running into is correct interaction with solana web3.js to get the wallet addresses
rather than the token program addresses
I want to map the token owner accounts (holders) of a specific token via the mint address. My issues is the correct call function against the api to obtain the owner/public key of the holders rather than just the token program values

please provide more details

I want to map the token owner accounts (holders) of a specific token via the mint address. My issues is the correct call function against the api to obtain the owner/public key of the holders rather than just the token program values

correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to fetch all owners of a certain token mint?

correct
https://codefile.io/f/96yUwnnsUI
here is current method im using, but this is just by largest account, not ALL wallets holding a token

Does this answer your question? Retrieving all holders of a given token

Will get back tannks

Check out a previous answer to this question Retrieving all holders of a given token
check out this blog post on how to do so.
